# Unknown "urlFor" function Silm Framework v 3x

Tags: php, twig, slim

I am using slim framework v 3x and twig. It seems urlFor is not recognozied
here is how I am using urlFor

```
<a class="sidebar-menu-button" href="{{urlFor('dashboard')}}">
```

The content of my route file is as

```
$app->get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController:dashboard', function ($request, $response, $args) {

    return $response;

})->setName('dashboard');
```

Where I am wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Need to use path_for() instead

```
<a class="sidebar-menu-button" href="{{path_for('dashboard')}}">
```